# IntelliJ Project Bar Files Highlighted, Turn Off

Tags: intellij-idea

**In IntelliJ**

I can't find this anywhere but I am trying to get that tan/grayish box to not be there so I can have just the black background, but it seems to highlight whatever I'm working on just like the tabs to the right. But I don want that big highlight.

Does anyone know the seting to turn that off?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Settings** > **Appearance & Behavior** > **File Colors** and you will see 3 check-boxes on top. Disable first one `Enable File Colors` and it will remove shade you are referring to.

Also disable `Use in Project View` but `Enable File Colors` should cover all **File Colors**